# I was told I can't use max-width and have to use min-width in css

Tags: css

This is with @media screen and (max-width:700px) {

https://i.gyazo.com/eab7c69146b5d47f3ce9adefae6e712d.png

When I do @media screen and (min-width:700px) { It gets screwed up. How do I change it to min-width without it messing up?

https://gyazo.com/3c27f20efe29a4cf001bf531dac59405.png

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more of your code?

Comment: the problem seems to be the cat quiz part. If you share your codes, we can decipher them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

}

this will surly help you

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `min-widht` and `max-width` and also combine them if you want.

`min-width` example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

`max-width` example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

`min-width` and `max-width` combination example:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

Note that I used *767.98px* for the `max-width` because the next media rule would be for example `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {}`.

Read more about media rules [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). You can also view how media rules are used in bootstrap [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).